# Pentaho Related Object

Tags: custom-object

I am trying to conduct a upsert on an object by pentaho , but this recendo the following error "Invalid Field: No such column 'Nova_Categoria__c:IdCategoria__c/IdcategoriaPai__r'", but the field exists in the object.

I am setting up the Pentaho as follows:
[image]

My Object:
[image]

Anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm excited to see there are other Kettle users in the Salesforce world :)

The error you're experiencing is I think a common UI confusion with the Kettle Salesforce integration.  The integration improperly returns a lookup field's relationship name rather than its field name.  Try changing the "Module field" column to just the field name: IdCategoriaPai__c.

One other fun UI glitch that commonly annoys me is that you must hit enter after editing the cell otherwise your edit will be reverted when leaving the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by breaking the XML file in Part 3 and up separately.
Thank you all